# How to get rid of em.persist();

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-transactions

I dont like to write em.persist() anymore. Can i do this while returning the new instance?

Hm well, maybe id confuse with grails-domains.

In example i got a AppConfig.java:

```
package spring;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.*;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        bean.setPersistenceUnitName("persistenceUnit");
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("session")
    public Test test() {
        return new Test();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager txManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }

    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        return txManager();
    }
}
```

and a Entity User

```
package spring;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity @Table(name = "User")
public class User {
    private long id;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }


    private String name;
    @Column
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getName() { return name; }

}
```

a persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="/META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and a hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory name="sessionFactory">
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">false</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:jamsession</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
            <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql">false</property>
            <mapping class="spring.User" />
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

a Controller named Test:

```
package spring;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Controller
public class Test {
    @PersistenceContext
    transient EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public User newUser(String name) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        // em.persist(user);
        return user;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return em.createQuery("from User").getResultList();
    }
}
```

and last but not least, this index.jsp:

```
<%@page import="spring.User"%>
<%@page import="spring.Test"%>
<%@page import="org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext"%>
<%@page import="org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils"%>
<%
    WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
    Object o = wac.getBean("appConfig");
    Test test = (Test) wac.getBean("test");
    if (request.getParameter("insert") != null) {
        test.newUser(request.getParameter("name"));
    }
%>
<ol>
<% for (User u : test.getUsers()) {
     out.print("<li>"+u.getName()+"</li>");
   } %>
</ol>

<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="unnamed" />
  <input type="submit" value="Insert" name="insert" />
</form>
```

To save new Users using the insert-button, i need em.persist(user);! How can i get rid of em.persist?

Comment: I don't understand.  Why do you want to remove em.persist?  It is vital to the operation of Hibernate, it will have to be called at some point.  I suppose you could always use em.merge instead if you just don't like typing those characters but that seems counter-intuitive and you will end up with strange cascades.

Comment: **kidding-mode:on** yes i hate the characters in this order **kidding-mode:off**. Well it is vital to the operation of persistence-frameworks, its not so correct to reduce this fact down to hibernate ;D. See, id like to be more general in code - i hope you understand what i mean - if anyone ask me if User will be saved i dont like to say yes, id like to say: all entitys are saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of `em.persist` using `AOP` :) you can do an annotation of yourself that after the function is being executed to do `em.persist()` of whatever it returns :)..

You can :

1. write an interceptor in case of java ee...
2. use [aspectj](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ) or AOP in case that you use spring
3. use some `DAO`s to manipulate objects

If you are using spring using AOP is much easier... just google it for AOP and invent whatever you want...

You can also use `spring-data` ... gives you a lot of stuff... just write an interface and you're done... `spring-data` will implement your interfaces...

Here you can see a `spring-data` project

1. [spring-data JPA](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-jpa-examples)
2. [an interface that will be implemented by spring (using AOP)](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-jpa-examples/blob/master/spring-data-jpa-example/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/example/repository/UserRepository.java)

P.S: it's not a joke... you don't have to write any implementation for that interfaces... you just have to use the naming conventions like "`save()`, `findUserByName(String name)`" etc...

Comment: I guess your approach is the best. Ill wait for better suggestions till tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this would be by using a [cascade](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Cascading) from a root object. In your case, perhaps `User`s belong to a `Department`. You could give that class a `@OneToMany` mapping to `User`, marked `CascadeType.ALL`:

```
@Entity
public class Department {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

Then to create a user, you would create it and add it to the `Department`:

```
Department d = em.find(Department.class, "Coinage");
User u = new User("Felix Schlag");
d.addUser(u);
```

When the enclosing transaction is committed, the existing but modified `Department` will be saved, and the save will cascade to the new `User` as well.

If there is no natural aggregation of `User`s such as a `Department`, you could create a single master root object for all users. Or you could classify users into types (administrators, customers, authors, whatever), and have a `UserType` instance for each, with a collection of all the users of that type.

I should finish by saying that while this approach is technically possible, i think it usually won't be a good idea. I would be nervous about running into problems related to having multiple threads update the root objects' collections concurrently (which might manifest as transaction commit failures), or to loading these giant collections into memory (which shouldn't be necessary, but might happen anyway).

Comment: Another good idea, too bad that i dont have a n-side everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. In addition you can:

- accomplish the same functionality with less code
- accomplish the same functionality with simpler code
- accomplish the same functionality with code that is easier to read
- accomplish the same functionality with code that is easier to understand
- be more productive
- reduce coupling (which makes your code less expensive to maintain)

You get all this by using GORM rather than CMP. Please note, this is just one point of view.

There is no industry consensus on this, nor the more general Spring persistence versus CMP debate. Therefore this should be thoroughly discussed by your organization.

Ideally pros and cons should be documented in an objective manner and weighed by real world evidence. Only then can your organization make informed decisions, and you should insist on it.

There are, unfortunately, people with "closely held beliefs" (aka strong opinions), which favor one over the other. IMHO the better architects are waiting for evidence-based results.

Opinion is, by nature, based on information that is gathered, interpreted, and time-based (meaning opinion changes over time, as more information is gathered and understanding improves.) It is a common problem in IT (IMHO) that decisions are based less on evidence and more on the opinions of those with the most influence.

I have observed many people confuse opinion with fact.

Some IT leaders (Venkat Subramaniam for example) warn against the overuse of annotations, since they couple your code to specific implementations. Your code uses a large number of annotations.

One of the benefits of the Spring framework is that most classes have no reference to Spring, and are totally decoupled. The industry is in wide agreement that decoupling reduces the cost of maintenance.

Spring moved configuration from code to external (XML) configuration files. This was widely seen as a positive step in the evolution of application architecture.

The Grails and Ruby on Rails frameworks take the next step, eliminating the majority of configuration files via "convention over configuration".

One way to view your code snippets is that they revert back two generations, to a solution that is tightly coupled (ironically in order to take advantage of "new" technology.)

Again, this is just one opinion. But I find, in practice, very few organizations objectively weigh the pros and cons.

Comment: very informative, welcome eric, guess you will enrich stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a user domain object in database using hibernate - you simply **have to call `em.persist(user)` somewhere**. It is considered good practice to wrap persistent operations in *data access layer*. The data access layer uses `EntityManager` to perform common persistent operations like save, find, remove, list, count ...) and encapsulates manipulation with `EntityManager`. Above data access layer should be *transactional service layer* that provides business methods related to your application, for example `UserService` with method `createUserAccount` - the service layer calls data access layer to perform basic operations (for example inside a transaction saves an user and assigns him some security roles). Finally controllers in your application should communicate with the service layer only - this way you can abstract from low level ORM API.

Comment: Re: "It is considered good practice to wrap...", "Above data access layer should be...", "you ... have to call", "layer that provides business methods"